# Transient noise MediaPlayer startup - Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Simple Android app for playing sounds (cymbal, drum, etc) in Android Tablet
Using Android Studio
The app works in a tablet or phone, but the first time hits the button, there is a loud thump or crack, then the sound plays. If hit button again, no thump or crack. Noticeable when playing through an external amplifier.
I have tried setting media volume to 0, "(mp01.setVolume(zero,zero);" ) but noise still persists first time.
Where is it coming from?

```
package com.example.sound_01;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 float one = (float) 1.0;
 float half = (float) .5;
 float zero = (float) 0.0;
 float three = (float) .3;
 float six = (float) .6;

 Button btn01;

 MediaPlayer mp01;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
     setupAllMedia();

     btn01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (mp01.isPlaying()) {
                 mp01.stop();
                 mp01.release();
                 Setupmp01();
             } else {
                 mp01.start();
             }
         }
     });
 }

 private void setupAllMedia() {
     Setupmp01();
 }

 void Setupmp01() {
     mp01 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.crash2);
     mp01.setVolume(one,one);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue using webview with mediaplayer. I was getting noises when touching buttons and when a new track started playing. (Only on a Samsung tablet feeding through my stereo. No noises on my Pixel 2.)

In a different webview program, I had programmed button clicks using the JavaScript oscillator, and I noticed that when I set the button click volume to zero, my touches were silent.

So, in the mediaplayer program, I started an oscillator at a very low volume. All of the transient noises disappeared, button touches and mediaplayer - problem fixed.

Is this an issue with system oscillators not being initialized or shut down properly?